# PHP <Style> change background color of div

Tags: php, css, background-color

I have a variable with a score and I'm having php change the color of a div element based on this variable. This if statement is always resolving to True. Anyone see the flaw?

```
    <style>
        .poster{
          background-color:<?php
            if($voteRating > 80.0){
            echo "#2ecc71;";
            }
            else{
            echo "#f1c42c;";
            }
            ?>
        }
        .year{
          color:;
        }
      </style>
```

Comment: Have you `var_dump`ed `$voteRating` to see what value it holds and more importantly what its type is?

Comment: Your $voteRating might not be what you think. What are you getting if you echo $voteRating ?

Comment: which data type is $voteRating? int or float, because 80.0 is float

Comment: Code seems okay, I think Havelock and Gimmy have a point, check `$voteRating`. You could also simplify your code like this: `echo ( $voteRating > 80.0 ) ? '#2ecc71;' : '#f1c42c';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would create two CSS classes and echo an appropriate class name on the element instead.

```
if($voteRating < 80)
{
  echo "<div class='one-class'>";
}
else
{
  echo "<div class='another-class'>";
}
```

Or, considering this is more of front-end thing, maybe use ajax to determine the $voteRating and then change the style with javascript. Just some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:-

```
<style>
    .poster{
      background-color:<?php echo ($voteRating > ceil(80.0)) ? "#2ecc71;" : "#f1c42c;"; ?>
    }
    .year{
      color:;
    }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with code. Try echoing $voteRanking to see if it gives more then 80.0

Comment: he is comparing with float value

Answer (score -1):

You should create different classes for each color and then use javascript or php conditions to set the class upon page rendering or any other event triggering. This way its easy to debug issues with your code.

for example

```
<style>
.posterhigh{
          background: #2ecc71;
}
.posterlow {
          background: #f1c42c;
}
</style>
```